# For loop not working with multiple input

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I can't get this to work when the user puts in more than one store number at `set /p store...`

If the user puts in 2 or more stores *(separated by space or comma or both)*, the first folder is created in `mkdir e:\Support\Vendor\PAUL\RHS\%store%` as expected; the rest are created in the directory the `.bat` is ran from.

Also the 2 lines starting `find /I` fail.

I have tried using `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` after `color A` with no luck.

```
@echo off
TITLE Sysinfo from SCH

color A

set /p store="Enter just the store number in this format 12345  "
echo %store% >> E:\Support\Vendor\PAUL\RHS\Store_list.txt

mkdir e:\Support\Vendor\PAUL\RHS\%store%
set sys=E:\Support\Vendor\PAUL\RHS\%store%\%store%_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%.txt

for /F %%s in (E:\Support\Vendor\PAUL\RHS\Store_list.txt) do (
    "E:\Support\MTS\Utilities\PSEXEC\psexec.exe" \\US%%sSCH01 -n 90 -d -w "\\US%%sSCH01\c$\SystemInfo" "\\US%%sSCH01\c$\SystemInfo\SysInfo.cmd"

    find /I "System Model =" \\US%%sSCH01\c$\SystemInfo\SysInfo.txt >> %sys%
    find /I "Serial Number:" \\US%%sSCH01\c$\SystemInfo\SysInfo.txt >> %sys%

    echo %%s,>>E:\Support\Vendor\PAUL\RHS\DONE_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.txt

)
```

Comment: Do you want to allow them to input more than one store when you prompt them for a store number?

Comment: Your input specifically asks for the format, `"Enter just the store number in this format 12345  "`. If the end user enters multiple stores separated by spaces and/or commas, your code should return them back to the question, because they've failed to use the stipulated format!

Comment: technically you are correct. the original version allowed for multi stores, but since I couldn't get it to work, I had to signify a single store. I would like them to be able to add multi store and I would like it to input it into Store_List.txt with each store on a separate line if there is a designation for that.

Comment: Then you need to move your `set sys=` into the for.